# How to create a sparse CSCMatrix using Spark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, matrix, pyspark

The documentation of Spark, for creating a `pyspark.ml.linalg.SparseMatrix` says:

```
Column-major sparse matrix. The entry values are stored in Compressed
Sparse Column (CSC) format. For example, the following matrix

   1.0 0.0 4.0 
   0.0 3.0 5.0
   2.0 0.0 6.0   

is stored as values: [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], 
rowIndices=[0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2], 
colPointers=[0, 2, 3, 6]
```

Can you explain how do we derive the `colPointers`? It says that they represent the index corresponding to the start of a new column, but still I cannot wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using characters in the matrix instead of floats makes reading it easier:

```
a 0 d 
0 c e
b 0 f
```

is stored as

```
values: [a, b, c, d, e, f]
rowIndices: [0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2]
colPointers: [0, 2, 3, 6]
```

- `values` are your non-null values from the matrix
- `rowIndices` maps the values from `values` to their row indices in the matrix, i.e., `a` is stored in row 0; `b` is stored in row 2, `c` is stored in row 1 ...  So there is one row index per value in `values`
- `colPointers` splits the `values` into columns. So we can represent `values` list as `[|a, b,| c,| d, e, f|]`, with `|` as splitters at indices 0, 2, 3, 6  in the list `values`:

  - `a` and `b` belong to the the first colum
  - `c` belongs to the second column
  - `d`, `e` anf `f` belong to the third column
  - Note that `ColPointers` allways starts with 0 and ends with a number wich is the length of `values` (`6` here)